# ATC vs ATO Fuses

Tags: fuses

I read about the difference between ATC vs ATO fuses here:

https://www.grainews.ca/2015/03/30/how-to-identify-blade-fuses/

Which states:

> The ATC has a fuse element that is closed (hence the “C” in the code) inside the plastic housing, sealing it from the environment to prevent corrosion from developing. The ATO fuse is open on the bottom, exposing the fuse element between the blades. ATC fuses are the best choice for use on machinery where they could be exposed to the weather. The high probability of corrosion build up could eventually interfere with current flow on an ATO type exposed to moisture.

In this case, why would anyone bother using an ATO when ATC's are better? Also, why does anyone manufacture ATO's? Is it cost related?

Comment: It specifically says that if exposed to the environment, you should use ATC fuses.  For example, if you have a system that is exposed to moisture, change in temperature, or change in humidity.  ATO fuses are cheaper and as reliable depending on the environment.

Comment: So the only incentive is cost if the environment is noncorrosive?

Comment: Also, an ATO fuse allows you to test it without removing the fuse from the application board it is on.